# Looking for non-entry level implementation of foundational algorithms and data structures in python. where to look?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I'm an autodidact who works best with a mix of theory and implementation examples. I'm having a hard time finding resources on implementing algorithms and data structures in Python (2.7-3.X  preferably). I found a text ...mastering basic algorithms in the python language but I find it to be far too introductory and thus cluttered with unnecessary prose, which makes it for me difficult to move efficiently over it. What I have in mind is a text or github gist or whatever really, that has some coded python imps of what I've determined to be foundational data-structures in algorithmic's(not to sure on the usage/conjugation of that). Specifically I'm looking for trees, traversal, dynamic and greedy algorithms and the like. If this question is a repeat, or adequately answered elsewhere, links are adequate replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Eppstein has a bunch of algorithms implemented in Python in his [PADS repository](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/).